# Join two pandas data frames with the indices of the first?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, `df1`:

```
    column1     column2
0   A           B
1   A           A
2   C           A
3   None        None
4   None        None
```

and `df2`

```
    id          l
40  100005090   A
188 100020985   B
```

Now I want to join `df1` and `df2`, but I don't know how to match the indices. If I simply do `df1.join(df2)`, the indices are aligned to `df2`. That is, it finds the 40th entry of `df2` and that is now the first entry of the dataframe that starts at 40 (`df1`). How do I tell pandas to align indices to `df1`, meaning that the first entry of `df2` is actually index 40? That is, I would like to get:

```
    id          l    column1     column2
40  100005090   A          A           B
188 100020985   B          A           A
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a slice of your df that is the same length as `df1`, then you can overwrite the index values and then `join`:

```
In [174]:    
sub = df.iloc[:len(df1)]
sub.index = df1.index
df1.join(sub)

Out[174]:
            id  l column1 column2
40   100005090  A       A       B
188  100020985  B       A       A
```

If the dfs are the same length then the first line is not needed, you just overwrite the index with the index values from the other df.

Comment: Ed, they are the same length already. Any shorter solution, just for the heck of it?

Comment: If they're the same length then the first line isn't needed, you just need to overwrite the index of the other df